# GNOME is gone. How to fix?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, upgrade, ppa, downgrade

I have had this issue for a few weeks. I use Ubuntu 14.04. I love GNOME and decided to upgrade to 3.12.

Then I later decided to downgrade to 3.10, using `ppa-purge`. I ran `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and rebooted. Now I cannot find GNOME in my desktop selection menu.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should install the GNOME desktop again. `ppa-purge` removed the GNOME packages and if there is no equivalent packages in the repositories, it downgrades nothing.

Therefore

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to reinstall GNOME to available version,

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

Remember to choose **LightDM** when prompted for it during the installation. Use Tab to move between the choices and Enter to confirm your selection.

Once installed, log out of the system and click on the Ubuntu icon besides the login field. Choose **GNOME from the drop down**: